# ParseExcel worksheet get_name()

Tags: perl, parseexcel

Using certain old versions of ActivePerl, reading a spreadsheet:

```
use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;
$excel = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::Workbook->Parse("some file");
foreach $sheet (@{$excel->{Worksheet}}){
  print $sheet->get_name(); 
}
```

Error: `Can't locate object method get_name() spreadsheet::parseexcel::worksheet`

Also `$sheet->{name}` doesn't give anything.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach my $sheet ($excel->worksheets) {
    print $sheet->get_name;
}
```

works. You are supposed to call the [`worksheets` method](http://p3rl.org/Spreadsheet%3a%3aParseExcel#worksheets-) to get at the Worksheets objects.

Answer (score 1):

Versions of [Spreadsheet::ParseExcel](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Spreadsheet-ParseExcel/) prior to 0.43 (January 2009) didn't have a `get_name()` method.

If you upgrade to a recent version of Spreadsheet::ParseExcel then your code will work. I tested it.

However, `Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::Workbook->Parse()` is now deprecated since it doesn't do error checking. Use `Spreadsheet::ParseExcel->Parse()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

**$sheet->{Name}** (with uppercase) gives the name, in v0.49 of ParseExcel

Comment: there's no API to bypass in that version